# Outlook VBA save attachment - timestamp on right side of filename

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

We just have a macro that saves file attachments to disk. What we're looking for is to have the timestamp after the name of the file, but in testing the file extension seems to be part of the name.

ie: testfile 2023-03-08 12-57-34.csv

is what we're looking for

```vb
Public Sub nameremoved(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)


    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder, sFileName As String
    Dim dt As String
    sSaveFolder = "location removed"
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy-dd-mm hh-mm-ss ")
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        sFileName = LCase(oAttachment.FileName)
        If sFileName Like "*.csv" Then
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & dt & oAttachment.DisplayName
        End If
    Next
    
    MItem.UnRead = False

End Sub
```

variations of oAttachment.

Comment: Maybe something like `oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & Replace(oAttachment.DisplayName, ".csv", dt & ".csv")`  It's unclear whether `oAttachment.FileName` and `oAttachment.DisplayName` are the same, or different for the mails you're processing.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method saves the attachment to the specified path. The location at which to save the attachment is passed as a parameter. The `DisplayName` property value may contain forbidden symbols not allows for file names. So, before relying on the property value I'd suggest removing such symbols from the string:

```
Function ReplaceIllegalCharacters(strIn As String, strChar As String) As String
    Dim strSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    strSpecialChars = "~""#%&*:<>?{|}/\[]" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

    For i = 1 To Len(strSpecialChars)
        strIn = Replace(strIn , Mid$(strSpecialChars, i, 1), strChar)
    Next

    ReplaceIllegalCharacters = strIn 
End Function
```

The result method may look like that:

```
Public Sub nameremoved(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)


    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder, sFileName As String
    Dim dt As String
    sSaveFolder = "location removed"
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy-dd-mm hh-mm-ss ")
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        sFileName = LCase(oAttachment.FileName)
        If sFileName Like "*.csv" Then
            Dim normalizedFileName As String = ReplaceIllegalCharacters(oAttachment.DisplayName, "_")
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & Replace(normalizedFileName  , ".csv", dt & ".csv")
        End If
    Next
    
    MItem.UnRead = False

End Sub
```